# Is it possible to make a script to update rows with values of same table but different logic?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this with data in it:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field               | Type                | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11)             | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| institution_id      | int(11)             | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| filename            | varchar(200)        | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| name                | varchar(200)        | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| md5                 | varchar(32)         | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| version             | varchar(200)        | NO   |     |                     |                |
| app_order           | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| active              | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| availability_oem    | varchar(25)         | NO   |     | Not Available       |                |
| availability_stb    | varchar(25)         | NO   |     | Not Available       |                |
| availability_retail | varchar(25)         | NO   |     | Not Available       |                |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Right now there is a unique constraint (institution_id + name).
I still want to have the unique contraint but just on 'name' column and I want that rows that have the same name right now but different institution_id get deleted until there is just one row with that name, so the name stay unique.
Example:

```
institution_id | name   | other_fields....
1              | jose   | ..
2              | jose   | ..
3              | maria  | ..
1              | maria  | ..
4              | pedro  | ..
5              | mateus | ..
5              | jose   | ..
```

So after that script run it will remain just one jose, one maria, one pedro, and one mateus, which one of them doesn't really matter but if I could choose it would be good.

Comment: "doesn't really matter" !!! IT SHOULD MATTER !!

Comment: @Strawberry it doesn't REALLY matter but it matters a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get uniq names grouping results:

```
SELECT id from table GROUP BY name;
```

Now you can delete everything unless these id's:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id from table GROUP BY name)
```

Hope to be helpfull

Comment: If you wanted to choose the row that would not be deleted from the rows with same name, how could you do it?

Comment: How do you know which rows want to keep? Any relation with institution_id?

Comment: I managed it already.
I'll mark your answer as correct since I didnt mention choosing the rows I wanted to keep